# Installation Failed [Errno 30] Read-only file system faulty CD/DVD, drive, hard disk

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 13.04 using Flash drive and DVD, but all times I get this error. What does it say? And how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1311565).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting again from CD, but this time press any key when the small logo appears at the bottom of your screen, to gain access to the advanced menu screen.  Once you get to it, do Check disk for defect, and Test memory.  That will tell you if there are any problems with hadware.

[image]

Also try verifying the ISO file, by running an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on it, and try burning another CD/DVD at slower speed.

Comment: Thank you, I checked for defects but no errors found. But this is screenshot from test memory: http://imgur.com/s5wS7rd.jpg what is is? And md5 is checked and is same and correct.

Comment: It looks like you have bad RAM.  How many memory modules do you have?

Comment: I have laptop not pc, it does not have memory module, but it has 4 GB ram. Is this you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  It may have a  memory module, or two.

Comment: Yes, You're right. My hardware has problems. I decided to change them. Thank you dear Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

***OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 (desktop-amd64)

**HW:** Acer One S1003*

I got this message on several devices when installing Ubuntu/Linux Mint from a USB flash drive. I solved the problem by **using a different USB flash drive.**

If I use a micro SD USB reader with a 32GB SD card (which I normally use for this) or a USB3 flash drive as the installation media, I get this error message. But when I used "Kingston DataTraveler 100 G2 16GB" the installation was successful.

**Result:** I assume that this problem manifests itself in an older, or special HW, when it is necessary to use a USB2 drive with a maximum capacity of 16GB.